# Javascript/Prototype scope confusion

Tags: javascript, scope, prototypejs

I'm creating a JavaScript class (using Prototype) that will set the page state to idle if there's no mouse movement within a specified number of seconds. When the mouse moves, the class will "wake up" the page by sending a message to a list of listeners.

The thing I don't understand is that `this.handlers` is valid in one function (`setIdle`), but not another (`setActive`). The annotated code below illustrates my problem:

```
var IM2 = Class.create({

handlers: null,

initialize: function(callback, frequency) {
    this.handlers = [];
    Event.observe(document, "mousemove", this.sendActiveSignal);
    Event.observe(document, "keypress", this.sendActiveSignal);
    setInterval(this.sendIdleSignal.bind(this), 5000);
},

addListener: function(h) {
    console.log(this.handlers.size());  // it's 0 here, as expected
    this.handlers.push(h);
    console.log(this.handlers.size());  // it's 1 here, as expected
},

sendIdleSignal: function(args) {
    console.log("IDLE");
    this.handlers.each(function(i){
        i.setIdle();
    })
},

sendActiveSignal: function() {
                                    // this.handlers is undefined here. Why?
    this.handlers.each(function(r) {
        r.setActive();
    })
}

});
```

Comment: You have an extra comma at the end of the object, that could create some weird errors, but I doubt that's the problem here. What gets logged if you do a console.log(this) inside sendActive()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean it's valid in SendIdleSignal and it's not valid in SendActiveSignal...

Your event listeners should also use bind, like this:

```
Event.observe(document, "mousemove", this.sendActiveSignal.bind(this));
Event.observe(document, "keypress", this.sendActiveSignal.bind(this));
```

Also, if you're using prototype 1.6 or higher, you can use

```
document.observe("mousemove", this.sendActiveSignal.bind(this));
document.observe("keypress", this.sendActiveSignal.bind(this));
```

Additionally, if you want a generic (framework agnostic) way to do this, you could define your functions like this:

```
sendActiveSignal: function() {
    var that = this;
    return function() {
        that.handlers.each(function(r) {
            r.setActive();
        });
    }
}
```

then your event handlers/setInterval could be left as

```
Event.observe(document, "keypress", this.sendActiveSignal);
```